# how do you know if a project is maven project in eclipse?

Tags: maven

If I check out a project which i have not created or worked on from svn server in eclipse. What would be the way to identify it is a maven project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it has pom.XML file in the root directory, it's maven

Comment: yes, i see a pom.xml file in the project root directory.

Comment: @D Volsky: if a maven project is checked out to my local box, does it mean maven is installed in my local box?

Comment: It doesn't, but I think eclipse ships with embedded maven version.